# Guardar partes de un String en distintas variables utilizando expresiones regulares y funcion java split

Tags: java, regex, split

Tengo un problema con estas expresiones regulares. Basándome en el siguiente código y sabiendo que el contenido de wemcamDetails es:

```
USB\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\6&9F9657C&0&1200                : Lenovo EasyCamera
```

Código:

```java
String line = "";
if ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    if (line.startsWith("USB")){
        webcamDetails = line;
    }
}

String regEx1 = "^\\S*";
String regEx2 = "\\:(.*)";

String[] webcamID = webcamDetails.split(regEx1);
System.out.println("Device ID: "+webcamID[0]);

String[] webcamDeviceName = webcamDetails.split(regEx2);

System.out.println("Device Name: "+webcamDeviceName[0]);
```

Quiero guardar `USB\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\6&9F9657C&0&1200` en la variable webcamID, y `Lenovo EasyCamera` en `webcamDeviceName`. He probado las expresiones regulares en varios regex testers y funcionan, pero por alguna razón que desconozco no me está guardando bien en las variables, siempre me guarda la primera parte del String, pero jamás guarda el nombre de la cámara. ¿Alguien que controle me puede decir qué és lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás utilizando `split()`, por lo que el texto devuelto en `webcamID[0]` y `webcamDeviceName[0]` es **lo que se encuentra antes de la primera coincidencia**.

En cambio, en vez de usar split(), podemos usar [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), con una única expresión regular que:

1. Verifique que comienza con `USB`.
2. Utilice [grupos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) (paréntesis) para capturar los 2 textos independientemente.

**Expresión regular:**

```
^(USB\S*)\s*:\s*(.*)
```

**Código:**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "^(USB\\S*)\\s*:\\s*(.*)";
final String string = "USB\\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\\6&9F9657C&0&1200                : Lenovo EasyCamera";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String webcamID = matcher.group(1);
    String webcamDeviceName = matcher.group(2);

    System.out.println("Device ID: "+webcamID);
    System.out.println("Device Name: "+webcamDeviceName);
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Device ID: USB\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\6&9F9657C&0&1200
Device Name: Lenovo EasyCamera
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/Nxwt3r

---

**Alternativa con `split`**

Otra opción que sí utilizaría split(), sería partiendo al texto en:

```
\s*:\s*
```

Es decir, cualquier cantidad de espacios, seguidos de `:` y más espacios opcionales.

```java
final String regex = "\\s*:\\s*";
final String string = "USB\\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\\6&9F9657C&0&1200                : Lenovo EasyCamera";

String[] webcam = string.split(regex);

System.out.println("Device ID: "+webcam[0]);
System.out.println("Device Name: "+webcam[1]);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/OOAGOl

Sin embargo, esto también dividiría al string si tuviese un símbolo `:` dentro del *ID* o el *Name*. Además, no me convence: te recomiendo la primera opción.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Lo he probado y funciona perfectamente, me estaba volviendo loco intentando probar suerte con StringTokenizer... en fin, +1 para usted ;)